# The return type 'String' isn't a 'Null', as required by the closure's context

Tags: flutter

Error at line: setState(() => controller.text = formattedDate); 
Error shows: "The return type 'String' isn't a 'Null', as required by the closure's context." 
Using dart null safety sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0" , How can I solve this?

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      child:
        TextFormField(
      controller: controller,
      validator: (value) {
        if (value!.isEmpty) {
          return errorMessage;
        }
        return null;
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: hintText,
              suffixIcon: controller.text.length > 0 ? IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                controller.clear();
              icon: Icon(Icons.cancel, color: Colors.grey))
                  : null
                ),
          readOnly: true,
          onTap: () async {
            DateTime? pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
                context: context,
                initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                firstDate: DateTime(1900),
                lastDate: DateTime(2040));
            if (pickedDate != null) {
              print(pickedDate); 
              String formattedDate = DateFormat('MMM d, yyyy').format(pickedDate);
              print(formattedDate); 
              setState(() => controller.text = formattedDate);
            } else {
              print("Date is not selected");
            }
          },
        ),
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Not sure if related but the code as you have now doesn't have matching brackets. `controller.clear();` needs to be `controller.clear();},` to make that matching.

Comment: how do you define controller?

Comment: // class CustomDateTextFieldForm extends StatelessWidget {
//   final TextEditingController controller;
//   final String hintText;
//   final String errorMessage;
//
//   const CustomDateTextFieldForm({
//     Key? key,
//     required this.controller,
//     required this.hintText,
//     required this.errorMessage,
//   }) : super(key: key);

Comment: Does `setState(() {controller.text = formattedDate;});` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are all muddled on your closures.  Your onTap is inside your InputDecoration and you don't have a condition on your icon inside that same InputDecoration, you are missing a closure ) for the GestureDetector.

I'd start with installing Dart on your IDE so you can get help with those kinds of syntax issues